# How to get cross-validated correlation estimate?

Tags: probability, logistic, correlation, cross-validation, spearman-rho

I have a logistic regression model trained on an outcome variable $y$ and I want to get an estimate of how good the predicted raw probabilities are in terms of aligning with $y$. I realize that logistic regression probabilities should not be expected to show a linear trend with the outcome variable but I would imagine that if it was well-trained, there might be a strong rank correlation at least.

Either way, whether this is a linear or logistic model, what is the best way to assess the correlated strength in a generalizable way? I though about doing 10-fold cross validation and testing the spearman correlation in each fold and averaging those but I don't know if that makes any sense. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logistic regression outputs probabilistic predictions for a new case to belong to the focal class. The standard approach to assess such probabilistic predictions is to use proper [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules). You can find more information and pointers to literature in [the tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info).

Comment: Thanks! But is there a standard way of assessing the generalizable correlation between outcome variable and a predictor in a dataset? Suppose we had a different task of linear regression with a continuous outcome variable and we found strong Pearson's $r$ with some feature. How would we know that this would generalize?

Comment: (1) As I wrote, I would not use correlation between predicted probabilities and observed (0-1) outcomes to assess a model. (2) Generalization is a general problem, not limited to a particular evaluation metric. You can't do much better than collecting a large evaluation sample from the population that you will apply your model to.